# How to print the category value in react native

Tags: json, react-native

{
"success": true,
"data": [
{
"price_id": "3",
"product": "456",
"category": "53 Grade Cement",
"brand": "22",
"price": "290",
"price_unit": "bag",
"seller_id": null,
"status": "1",
"created_on": "2021-03-04 00:00:00",
"category_name": "Cement",
"brand_name": "Ramco"
}
]
}

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing you are trying to request some data from server. So you've managed to request and get the data. Assign that data to a variable called `response` and then
you could just to this `response.data[0].category`.